# jquery nivoslider working on localhost but stops working once I am on the internet

Tags: jquery, localhost, nivo-slider

my jquery nivoslider works well on my localhost but stops working immediately I am connected to the internet, please what can I do, I have switched off my bxslider

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>

Comment: So check that you have a folder containing your HTML file and a sub-folder 'scripts' containing the files 'jquery-1.9.0.min.js' and 'jquery.nivo.slider.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to use JS for some effects inside magento,

jQuery.noConflict(); also resolved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the problem, I discovered there was a jquery conflict so I did this

1. var j = jQuery.noConflict();

   j(window).load(function() {
       j('#slider').nivoSlider();
   });